# How to automatically load values from one table column to another in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am using Mysql 8.0
I have 2 tables given below:

```
Table 1:
    I_VendorID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    V_Code VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    V_Name VARCHAR(250) NULL,
    V_Address VARCHAR(500) NULL,
    N_Mobile NUMERIC(10, 0) NULL,
    N_Phone NUMERIC(11, 0) NULL,
    V_Email VARCHAR(100) NULL,

Table 2:
     I_POID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
     I_VendorID INT NULL,
     V_PODetails VARCHAR(50) NULL
```

I wish to know if there is any way, either through query code or through mysql workbench that whatever value is in table 1 under I_VendorID is automatically copied to I_VendorID in table 2. 
I will always be taking the values from the user for the 2 tables at the same time. Also declared I_VendorID in table 2 as a foreign key. I thought, rather than passing values manually for I_VendorID from table 2 everytime, I could just copy the value from table 1. Is there any query or method that would automatically ensure this?

Comment: normally if you want to action table2 automatically when you action table1 you would use a trigger  but since you will 'always be taking the values from the user for the 2 tables at the same time' I'm not sure a trigger is appropriate or necessary.

Comment: Note that phone numbers aren't really 'numeric'. They are 'strings' comprising only of digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use mysql triggers to make sure that for each row inserted in your first table, another row is inserted in the second table

[MySql documentation on triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)

```
CREATE TRIGGER ins_to_table_2 BEFORE INSERT ON table_1
       FOR EACH ROW
       BEGIN
           insert into table_2('I_VendorID') values(New.I_VendorID)
       END;//
```

I have not executed the above yet, but it's something very similar.

Truth be told though, since you will eventually add a row in the second table, you can insert it when needed and query with a left join instead of inner join so that you can return the values from the first table, even if the second one has no values yet.